# Converging/Diverging Series with Factorial

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm looking to determine whether the series converges or diverges. I don't know how to handle this series due to the factorial in the numerator and denominator. Any help is appreciated!!
$$a_n = \frac{ (-1)^{n+1} (n!)^2}{(2n)!}$$

Comment: It turns out the series can be evaluated in closed form. Casting the series as a hypergeometric function and throw it to wolfram alpha, wolfram alpha return $\frac{1}{25}\left(5 + 4\sqrt{5}\sinh^{-1}\left(\frac12\right)\right)$. There must be a simpler way to evaluate this answer directly instead of just getting the convergence.

Comment: See also [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation).

Comment: Generally speaking, $$\dfrac{(n!)^2}{(2n)~}=\dfrac1{2n\choose n}\qquad;\qquad\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(2x)^{2n}}{{2n\choose n}n^2}=2\arcsin^2x$$ By differentiating twice, we find the answer to your question, $$(1-x^2)\cdot\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(2x)^{2n}}{2n\choose n}=1+\frac x{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\cdot\arcsin x$$ By making $x=\dfrac i2$ and exploiting the [relationship](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_formula) between [hyperbolic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function) and trigonometric functions, we finally arrive at **Achille Hui**'s closed form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ratio test. let $a_n = \frac{ (-1)^{n+1} (n!)^2}{(2n)!} $. Then

$$ \left| \frac{ a_{n+1}}{a_n} \right| =  \frac{(n+1)!^2}{(2n+2)! } \cdot \frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2} = \left( \frac{(n+1) n!}{n!} \right)^2 \cdot \frac{(2n)!}{(2n+2)(2n+1)(2n)!}= \frac{(n+1)^2}{(2n+2)(2n+1)} = \frac{n^2+2n+1}{4n^2+6n+2} \to \frac{1}{4}<1$$

Hence, the series converges

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
\begin{align}
&\color{#88f}{\large%
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\pars{-1}^{n + 1}\,{\pars{n}!^{2} \over \pars{2n}!}}
=\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\pars{-1}^{n + 1}\,\pars{2n + 1}\,
{\Gamma\pars{n + 1}\Gamma\pars{n + 1} \over \Gamma\pars{2n + 2}}
\\[3mm]&=\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\pars{-1}^{n + 1}\,\pars{2n + 1}\,
\int_{0}^{1}t^{n}\pars{1 - t}^{n}\,\dd t
=\int_{0}^{1}\bracks{
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\pars{-1}^{n + 1}\pars{2n + 1}t^{n}\pars{1 - t}^{n}}\,\dd t
\\[3mm]&=\int_{0}^{1}{%
t\pars{t - 1}\pars{t^{2} - t - 3} \over \pars{t^{2} - t - 1}^{2}}\,\dd t
=\int_{-1/2}^{1/2}
{\bracks{\pars{t^{2} - 3/4} + 1}\bracks{\pars{t^{2} - 3/4} - 2}
\over \pars{t^{2} - 3/4}^{2}}\,\dd t
\\[3mm]&=
2\int_{0}^{1/2}\bracks{1 - {1 \over t^{2} - 4} - {2 \over \pars{t^{2} - 4}^{2}}}\,\dd t
\\[3mm]&=\color{#88f}{\large{1 \over 25}\bracks{5 + 4\root{5}{\rm arctanh}\pars{\root{5} \over 5}}} \approx 0.3722
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

The series converges absolutely since: $|\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}| = \dfrac{(n+1)^2}{(2n+1)(2n+2)} \to \dfrac{1}{4} < 1$ when $n \to \infty$